# How do you select 2 rows from the same table in MySQL, with different conditions for each?

Tags: mysql, select, join

i have a table I am using for referrals.  The table has 3 columns: `ID, FriendCode, and Referred`.  I want to

- select `Referred` from the row where the ID = `currentUser`
- ID from the row where the FriendCode = `refereeFriendCode`,
- I want to do this with **one query**.

`ID | Referred | FriendCod
     1 |    1     |   100
     2 |    0     |   200`

I want to select 1 from referred column and 2 from ID column, and what I have is an ID of 1(current user) and FriendCode 200.

How do I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Is:

```
select ID from tablename where ID=1
union 
select ID from tablename where FriendCode=100
```

what you want?

Comment: This appears correct, but did not work for me and i'm not sure why.  I decided to just use two separate queries.

Comment: Could it be that certain servers don't allow UNION statements but don't throw an error either?

Comment: @JoeFiller No `UNION` is SQl standard and it must be implemented by all SQL bases DBMS